# "Exception AttributeError" on roscore launch

Tags: ros, roscore, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am receiving an error messages when I run `roscore` from the command line on Ubuntu 12.04.  Whatever the cause, I was still able to functionally complete the beginner's section of the [tutorial page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).

I installed ROS (as per the [installation instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu)), and I set the environment variables for a [single-machine network setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup#Single_machine_configuration).

The following is the output after executing `roscore` from the command line:

```
 developer@developer-VirtualBox:~/fuerte_workspace$ roscore
 ... logging to /home/developer/.ros/log/2de0d828-ee47-11e1-a20c-080027500e36/roslaunch-developer-VirtualBox-27454.log
 Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
 Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
 Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
 
 started roslaunch server http://developer-VirtualBox:55585/
 ros_comm version 1.8.10
 
 SUMMARY
 ========
 
 PARAMETERS
  * /rosdistro
  * /rosversion
 
 NODES
 
 auto-starting new master
 Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in      <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
 process[master]: started with pid [27470]
 ROS_MASTER_URI=http://developer-VirtualBox:11311/
 
 setting /run_id to 2de0d828-ee47-11e1-a20c-080027500e36
 Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in      <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
 process[rosout-1]: started with pid [27483]
 started core service [/rosout]
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this exception?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42262/%22exception-attributeerror%22-on-roscore-launch/) by [David Kaczynski](https://answers.ros.org/users/2982/david-kaczynski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2012-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't worry, it's harmless.

Frequent question - see: http://answers.ros.org/question/37087/potential-python-problem-in-ubuntu-1204-lts-64bit-and-fuerte/?answer=37088#post-id-37088

---

Originally posted by [rlinsalata](https://answers.ros.org/users/2578/rlinsalata/) with karma: 271 on 2012-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1